# StackMob REST Api application/Json response

Tags: ios, stackmob

I have recently transferred my app over to stack mob, however I'm having difficulty with using the REST Api within my AFHTTP framework.  Stackmob returns it's own version of the application/json response.  It is actually returned as application/vnd.stackmob+json;

The AFHttp framework doesn't accept this, therefore I need a way of either asking stackmob to only return a standard application/json response, or tweak AFHTTP to accept this customer stackmob response.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `Accept: application/vnd.stackmob+json` header to your NSURLRequest that you create?

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried that, it returns something back from stack mob, but AFHTTP expects a return type of application/json, but stack mob returns application/vnd.stackmob+json.  Although the formatting is in correct standard json formatting, AFHTTP doesn't understand the return type.  I was hoping there was a way to tell AFHTTP to also accept stack mob+json